# Is there a way to add a threshold to the charts in Azure Monitor?

Tags: azure, monitor, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I am building a dashboard to monitor some virtual machine data. I'd like for some of the charts to show a threshold like this

[image: threshold image]

However, it seems to only have a threshold when building Alerts. Is there another way to get this?

This was the only link I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log but not what I need as it's only for alerts.

Edit:
I found more information here about it. It's also called a reference line: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts. This should be the answer I want but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you add a reference line also called Threshold (blue line in screenshot). If you need more help add you kusto query and we can have a look why you are failing adding it.

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) 
| where CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize avg(CounterValue), percentiles(CounterValue, 50, 95)  by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| extend Threshold = 20
| render timechart
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. This has worked for me, but not for bar graphs. Is there a way to have a line but with bar graphs like in the doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts

Comment: @ColorfulCodes in the link in the comment there is no reference line on the column chart and i havnt been able to add one either, if adding in the same way as for a timechart it will just add the static value ontop of each bar. I can see that you can get one when setting up a query in an alert but cant reproduce it in a query.